# В чем разница между разработкой на C# в winforms и UWP?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

Расскажите в чем разница при разработке программы на C# в winforms и UWP? Есть ли разница в написании кода и если да то насколько? В данном вопросе ничего не знаю и интересно понять.

Comment: в тегах указываете `uwp`, а спрашиваете про какой-то "UPF"? Может вас интересует `WPF`?

Comment: Ошибся. Спрашиваю про UWP (Universal Windows Platform).

Comment: Кратко о `UWP`: 1) интерфейс адаптивный к разным размерам экрана и ориентации разрабатывается с помощью языка разметки `XAML`, произносится как "Замл", некоторые произносят как "Кзамл", но англоязычные так не говорят, 2) и это главное отличие - используется подмножество дотнет фрейморка библиотека классов WinRT, которая приехала к нам начиная с Windows 8, например там другие классы для работы с файловой системой, зато есть готовые классы для работы с видеокамерой, микрофоном, ориентацией и проч. Да, и еще, эти приложения рассчитаны на распространение только через магазин приложений.

Comment: какая разница вас интересует? если архитектурная, то почти во всем отличается включая используемые паттерны. В синтаксисе и особенностях языка разумеется отличий нет, те же классы структуры и все сопутствующее. Библиотеки, как уже написали, большей частью свои и почти не совместимы с классическим .NET, тоже верно и в обратную сторону. Жизненный цикл приложения больше похож на андроид и иос, в отличие от классической Windows модели "работает - не работает". Разница между UWP и WPF меньше, но не на много.

Comment: Но как дело обстоит в плане кода? Вот если у меня есть простая программа на winforms, я смогу просто скопировать код и вставить в UWP?

Comment: Отдельные куски кода вставить возможно. Впрочем, что спрашивать то? Сами попробуйте, создайте проект и экспериментируйте, это не страшно и не больно.

Comment: Куски кода из WinForms-проекта можно использовать повторно, если проект был написан с разделением логики, модели и представления. К сожалению, типичный WinForms-проект читает базу данных в OnClick, и там же обновляет кнопки и парсит HTML.

Comment: Если надо работать с базой данных на сервере, то UWP работает только с sqlite. Для работы с внешней базой, надо будет создавать web api приложение.

Comment: @VladD Куски кода из ***любого*** проекта можно использовать повторно, *если проект был написан с разделением логики, модели и представления*. К сожалению, типичный ***говнокод на любом фреймворке*** проект читает базу данных в OnClick, и там же обновляет кнопки и парсит HTML и *варит щи.*

Comment: @Kromster: Подписываюсь под каждым словом :)